# Find the last balance quantity per customer per month (Power Pivot)

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have the below dataset (*Table 1*), and I would like to create a new calculated column to only have the last Balance Qty per month for each customer.

The last column (*EOM Balance Qty*) illustrates what I need.

```
  -----------------------------------------------------
  |                     Table 1                       |
  ----------------------------------------------------- -------------------
  |     Date    | Customer | Type | Qty | Balance Qty | | EOM Balance Qty |
  |=============|==========|======|=====|=============| |=================|
  |  1/Jan/2019 | Alan     | Buy  |  15 |          15 | |                 |
  |-------------|----------|------|-----|-------------| |-----------------|
  |  2/Jan/2019 | Alan     | Use  |  10 |           5 | |               5 |
  |-------------|----------|------|-----|-------------| |-----------------|
  |  2/Feb/2019 | Alan     | Buy  |  30 |          35 | |                 |
  |-------------|----------|------|-----|-------------| |-----------------|
  |  3/Feb/2019 | Alan     | Use  |  10 |          25 | |              25 |
  |-------------|----------|------|-----|-------------| |-----------------|
  |  3/Mar/2019 | Alan     | Use  |  15 |          10 | |              10 |
  |-------------|----------|------|-----|-------------| |-----------------|
  |  4/Apr/2019 | Alan     | Buy  | 100 |         110 | |                 |
  |-------------|----------|------|-----|-------------| |-----------------|
  |  5/Apr/2019 | Alan     | Use  |  35 |          75 | |              75 |
  |-------------|----------|------|-----|-------------| |-----------------|
  |  1/Jan/2019 | Bob      | Buy  |  10 |          10 | |                 |
  |-------------|----------|------|-----|-------------| |-----------------|
  |  2/Jan/2019 | Bob      | Use  |  10 |           0 | |               0 |
  |-------------|----------|------|-----|-------------| |-----------------|
  | 20/Jan/2019 | Charlie  | Buy  | 100 |         100 | |             100 |
  |-------------|----------|------|-----|-------------| |-----------------|
  |  1/Feb/2019 | Charlie  | Use  |  20 |          80 | |              80 |
  |-------------|----------|------|-----|-------------| |-----------------|
  |  5/Apr/2019 | Charlie  | Use  |  10 |          70 | |                 |
  |-------------|----------|------|-----|-------------| |-----------------|
  | 30/Apr/2019 | Charlie  | Use  |  55 |          15 | |              15 |
  ----------------------------------------------------- -------------------
```

[Sample Excel File Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArK_XNBpksg4hepVaDchRqBaiKIX5w?e=Eb1C0O)

I have tried searching for a similar solution and the closes I got is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57119541/average-of-each-months-last-date-max-date-value). However, I am getting an error when I add it as a calculated column or measure in Power Pivot.

I have also tried using the `ENDOFMONTH` function, but some dates didn't return the result as they should.

```
= CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table1[closing_balance_qty] ), ENDOFMONTH ( Table1[Date] ) )
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated based on the comments:**

I modified your new source data as follows:

[image]

Instead of the previous column "Date", we will now use column "Date-Time", which contains date + time.

You will also need to add field "Year-Month" at the source file, not as a calculated column. Either ask your data source provider to add it for you, or use PowerQuery.

Next, create a calculated column:

```
EOM Balance Qty = 
VAR Last_Date_Time =
    CALCULATE ( 
      MAX ( Table1[Date-Time] ), 
      ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Customer], Table1[Year-Month] ) 
    )
RETURN
    IF ( Table1[Date-Time] = Last_Date_Time, CALCULATE(SUM ( Table1[Balance Qty] )))
```

Result:

[image]

How it works:

- First, we group data by Customer and Year-Month using ALLEXCEPT, and find max date-time within the group.
- Then, for the current record, we compare its date-time with the latest date-time we have found. If they are the same, we calculate the balance, otherwise return blank.

Comment: Many thanks. That worked most of the time, except when there are more than 1 transactions on the **last date** per customer. All rows of the last date will be returned, instead of just the last row. e.g. if there are _x2 'Use' of 5_, instead of _x1 'Use' of 10_, for Darby on 1/5/2019, it will return 1 row with 5 and the 2nd row with 0. How can we have only the last row be returned?

Comment: If there are multiple transactions per customer per date, then you simply don't have a way to identify "last row" - there is not enough information. Typically, I would use time (it clearly shows what is "last"), but you don't have time in your data.

Comment: It will be great if we can use time to determine the last tx, as my real data has timestamp, ie. 1/5/2019 13:08:00. I have updated the sample data, table1[Date], to include time, but then the formula returned "Calculation Error". I am still figuring how to edit the formula. And should I separate the time to a different column? [New Sample File](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArK_XNBpksg4hepVaDchRqBaiKIX5w?e=AaVhSb)